# How to know which gcc version to choose when compiling pytorch from source?

Tags: gcc, dependencies, pytorch

I am working on installing PyTorch from source but am unsure about the specific dependency versions to use for the version of PyTorch I want to install.

In particular, I noticed performance variations depending on the gcc version I use to compile PyTorch. Which compiler should I be using to get the best PyTorch performance?

Tensorflow doc provides such useful information. They call it "Tested build configurations":
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations.

Comment: `Does anyone know how to find this information?` Compile, test, aggregate results, repeat. Then compare. `Online documentation` looking for offsite resources is offtopic for stackoverflow. `building tips` Stackoverflow is a forum for specific programming questions and how to solve them. You may want to interest yourself in [how do we ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what topics can we ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Could you share more information about your observed performance instabilities? It's rather common to use the latest stable compilers (or OS defaults) and newer versions shouldn't introduce performance regressions (neither should PyTorch). If you observe those you should ask this question on PyTorch's github issues. Also Tensorflow only provides versions they tested against, not "the fastest one" (which doesn't mean much, it may get faster in one place and slower in another, hence you should look for topics about performance of specific parts(or their regressions)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README.md](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source) has instructions to build from source.

If you are installing from source, you will need a C++14 compiler. Also, we highly recommend installing an [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#download-section) environment. You will get a high-quality BLAS library (MKL) and you get controlled dependency versions regardless of your Linux distro.

Once you have [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#download-section) installed, here are the instructions.

If you want to compile with CUDA support, install

- [NVIDIA CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) 9 or above
- [NVIDIA cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) v7 or above
- [Compiler](https://gist.github.com/ax3l/9489132) compatible with CUDA

If you want to disable CUDA support, export environment variable `USE_CUDA=0`. Other potentially useful environment variables may be found in `setup.py`.

If you are building for NVIDIA's Jetson platforms (Jetson Nano, TX1, TX2, AGX Xavier), Instructions to install PyTorch for Jetson Nano are [available here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-nano-version-1-5-0-now-available/72048)

You can found Latest, official Compiler requirements [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

[image]

Comment: @UltimatePipo, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You