# Failed building pytorch from source: "CMake Error at cmake/MiscCheck.cmake" "Could not run a simple program built with your compiler"

Tags: cmake, pytorch, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I am trying to build `Pytorch` from source following [tutorial](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson/72048) on

- `Jetson`: Jetson 5.0.2 GA
- `os`: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS focal
- `cmake version`: 3.16.3, installed along with ROS noetic.
- `gcc`: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

The error occurred at the installation step `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`:

```
Building wheel torch-1.12.0
-- Building version 1.12.0
cmake -GNinja -DBUILD_PYTHON=True -DBUILD_TEST=True -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/gvsc/reddy_reddy/pytorch/torch -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages;/home/gvsc/Admin/Projects/racer_ws/devel:/opt/ros/noetic -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.8 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 -DTORCH_BUILD_VERSION=1.12.0 -DUSE_NCCL=0 -DUSE_NUMPY=True -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK=0 -DUSE_QNNPACK=0 /media/gvsc/reddy_reddy/pytorch
-- Could not find ccache. Consider installing ccache to speed up compilation.
-- Performing Test COMPILER_WORKS
-- Performing Test COMPILER_WORKS - Failed
CMake Error at cmake/MiscCheck.cmake:34 (message):
  Could not run a simple program built with your compiler.  If you are trying
  to use -fsanitize=address, make sure libasan is properly installed on your
  system (you can confirm if the problem is this by attempting to build and
  run a small program.)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:679 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/media/gvsc/reddy_reddy/pytorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/media/gvsc/reddy_reddy/pytorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

- `libasan` is installed as `libasan5`
- I also verified that the machine can use cmake to build a simple program by following the [cmake tutorial](https://github.com/pyk/cmake-tutorial). I could run `cmake .` to get `cmake-tutotrial` built.

If anyone can suggest a solution, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Weird, it might be worth it to try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` if you haven't already.

Comment: @user `gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`

Comment: related: [How to know which gcc version to choose when compiling pytorch from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61340939/11107541)

Comment: @user GCC version seems good based on the [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). Added my OS and GCC info in the question description.